# Printing all lists including empty lists in prolog

Tags: prolog

I am very new to prolog and I am stuck with this situation for quite a while.

I have these rules

```
show_meal(Meals) :- findall(X, chosen_meal(X), Meals).
show_bread(Breads) :- findall(X, chosen_bread(X), Breads).
show_meat(Meats) :- findall(X, chosen_meat(X), Meats).
show_veggie(Veggies) :- findall(X, chosen_veggie(X), Veggies).
show_sauce(Sauces) :- findall(X, chosen_sauce(X), Sauces).
show_topup(TopUps) :- findall(X, chosen_topup(X), TopUps).
show_side(Sides) :- findall(X, chosen_side(X), Sides).
show_order(Meals, Breads, Meats, Veggies, Sauces, TopUps, Sides) :-
          show_meal(Meals), show_bread(Breads), show_meat(Meats), show_veggie(Veggies),
          show_sauce(Sauces), show_topup(TopUps), show_side(Sides).
```

The problem I encountered is that if at least 1 of the list is empty in show_order, for example if show_meat(Meats) is empty, the prolog wouldnt be able print successfully and gives me and undefined procedure.

```
ERROR: Undefined procedure: chosen_meat/1
ERROR:   However, there are definitions for:
ERROR:         chosen_meal/1
```

Is there a way to overcome this situation? I would like to know if it is possible to still print show_order with this scenario. Thank you.

Comment: Well the error is quite clear, you never defined a `chosen_meat`. You can define a predicate `chose_mean` that is always false with `chosen_meat(_) :- fail`.

Comment: Hi @WillemVanOnsem thank you for pointing that out. I would also like to ask if I would like to print them out using write, how can this be achieved. I realised i cant put all 7 variables in a Write like this
print(Mealout,Breadout,Meatout,Veggieout,Sauceout,Topupout,Sideout).

Comment: you can create a list containing the seven values, or you write them one at a time.

Comment: You probably should check the documentation on output predicates and read the descriptions. Then play with them a bit to see what suits your needs.